# Finding the domain and range of $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find the domain and range of $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$

**My Attempt:** $1+\frac1x\gt0\implies\frac{x+1}x\gt0\implies x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty)$

$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\to e$

$\lim_{x\to-1}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\to \infty$

$\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\to 0$

So, I think the range should be $(0,e)\cup(e,\infty)$. Is this correct?

Major doubt: will $e$ be included in the range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually your third limit is wrong, $\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=1$ not $0$, so the correct range is $(1,e)\cup(e,\infty)$, $e$ is not in the range because $(1+1/x)^x$ is an increasing function on the positives which approaches $e$ as $x\to\infty$, and a increasing function on the negatives which approaches $e$ as $x\to -
\infty$.

Comment: Hi.$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\\\log L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+\frac1x)}{\frac1x}\\\log L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac1{1+\frac1x}\cdot-\frac1{x^2}}{-\frac1{x^2}}=\frac1{1+\infty}=0$$ What's wrong in my approach?

Comment: @aarbee You proved $\color{red}{\log} L =0$, not $L=0$

Comment: @jjagmath thankyou.